# Is there a way to know how much of our asking/answering/editing and other activities come from high rep users?

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to know how much of our asking/answering/editing and other activities come from high rep users? In other words, is there a way to see how many questions are asked by users over 2000 rep (other than counting, of course)?

Answer (score 9):

You could write a [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com) query.  Per [the schema in this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

1. using the `Posts` (questions and answers) and `PostHistory` (edits) tables,
2. you can narrow your query down by `PostTypeId` and `PostHistoryTypeId`,
3. then correlate the `UserId` with an `Id` in the `Users` table
4. and filter by that `UserId`'s `Reputation`

There are some places where that won't quite work; for example, in `PostHistory` a `UserDisplayName` field is populated when the user has been removed, so there are some edits where you won't be able to determine the reputation of the user involved.  `Reputation` also isn't stored as a function of time, so your population of "high reputation" users will change as more people climb through 2,000, retroactively changing whether some posts and edits were made by a "high reputation" user than not (conversely, temp bans reduce displayed reputation to 1 and presumably also do that to the reputation provided by the field in the `Users` table.)